# Cannot string together multiple "-c" options using vim from the terminal

Tags: command-line, vim

I execute a set of handy commands I need to do often on a standard type of file using the `-c` (or equivalently, the `+`) option from command line using vim. However, after an update to the remote system's OS, commands beyond the first one are interpreted as different file names and results in the first command being executed and multiple buffers being opened rather than multiple commands being executed on one file.

The command I use is `vim -c ':11' -c ':norm wllv,dZZ' myfile` (go to line 11, move over a few characters, select the current position, and replace using a leader command, and then save and exit).
With the change on the remote system, this now results in two buffers being opened, one is `wllv,dZZ` and the other is `myfile`

Vim also throws this error:

```
Error detected while processing command line:
E471: Argument required: :norm
```

Furthermore, if I try `vim -c ":11" -c ":21" myfile`, both commands work and no extra buffer is opened, which indicates the error is perhaps somewhere with `:norm`, but I'm not sure why as this was working just fine very recently.

Current version of vim is 7.4, in case that helps.

Any help restoring the old behavior or understanding where the issue is coming from would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: If you're doing this non-interactively, `ed`, the line editor is a better choice. Read `man ed`.

Comment: If this ends up being a vi/vim specific thing, I'll alert you to the existence of the [Vi and Vim Stack Exchange site](https://vi.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @JeffSchaller thanks for mentioning that, i didn't know there was a specific stack exchange just for vim! Asked there and will update here or there accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer here: https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/31833/37021
The issue was a bug in a wrapper function on the remote system that was passing the command line arguments incorrectly to the vim executable.

The fix was to alias vim to run the executable directly and file a bug report to the sys admins about the wrapper function.